$E((\ln X)^m)$ for Weibull Distribution.
I want to find the $E\left[ \left( \ln\left(X\right)\right)^m \right]$ for Weibull Distribution, which is $f_X(x;\tau,\theta)=\frac{\tau}{x}\left( \frac{x}{\theta}\right)^{\tau} e^{ -\left( \frac{x}{\theta}\right)^{\tau} }$. Need help on comment whether my approach is the right, or I should use other approach instead..
Here is my trials :
Firstly,
$$E\left[ \left( \ln\left(X\right)\right)^m \right] = \int^{\infty}_{0} \left( \ln\left(x\right)\right)^m \cdot \frac{\tau}{x}\left( \frac{x}{\theta}\right)^{\tau} e^{ -\left( \frac{x}{\theta}\right)^{\tau} } dx$$
By letting $y=\tau \ln\left( \frac{x}{\theta} \right)$, we have :
$$E\left[ \left( \ln\left(X\right)\right)^m \right] = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \left( \ln\left(\theta e^{\frac{y}{\tau}}\right)\right)^m \cdot e^{y} \cdot e^{e^{-y}} dy$$
Again, letting $e^y=u$ , we have
$$E\left[ \left( \ln\left(X\right)\right)^m \right] = \int^{\infty}_{0} \left( \ln\left(\theta \left( u \right)^{\frac{1}{\tau}} \right)\right)^m \cdot e^{u} du$$
But then I stuck... I have no clue to proceed by adding something to ease the integration process... can anyone give me alight on this...

You may have more luck creating a new random variable $Y = \ln X$ and then computing $E[Y^m]$. (It'll be make it much easier if you recognize $Y$ to have the pdf of a Gumbel distribution, a distribution that has a known mgf :).)

@Thành Nguyễn thanks.... I just tried, by letting $Y = \ln X$, I have $f_Y = k \lambda^{-k}e^{ky-e^{ky}\lambda^{-k}}$ , so I just need to find the $E[Y]$ ? Do you have the link of website or book regarding these? Thanks for the light anyway...

Let $X \sim \operatorname{Weibull}(\tau, \theta)$ with density $$f_X(x) = \frac{\tau}{x} \left(\frac{x}{\theta}\right)^\tau e^{-(x/\theta)^\tau}, \quad x > 0. \tag{1}$$  Here, $\tau$ is a shape parameter and $\theta$ is a scale parameter.  To facilitate computation, we standardize:  let $W = g(X) = (X/\theta)^\tau$, hence
$$f_W(w) = f_X(\theta w^{1/\tau}) \left|\frac{dg^{-1}}{dw}\right| = \frac{\tau}{\theta w^{1/\tau}} w e^{-w} \cdot \frac{\theta}{\tau} w^{1/\tau - 1} = e^{-w} , \quad w > 0 \tag{2}$$ and $W \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(1)$.  Then $G = \log W$ has density
$$f_G(g) = e^g f_W(e^g) = e^g e^{-e^g}, \quad g > 0, \tag{3}$$
which is standard Gumbel distributed with location $0$ and scale $1$.  Consequently, $$Y = \log X = \log \theta W^{1/\tau} = \log \theta + \frac{1}{\tau} \log W = \log \theta + \frac{G}{\tau}; \tag{4}$$ that is, $Y$ is Gumbel distributed with location parameter $\mu = \log \theta$ and scale parameter $\beta = 1/\tau$.  The MGF of $G$ is
$$\begin{align}
M_G(t) &= \operatorname{E}[e^{tG}] \\
&= \int_{g=-\infty}^\infty e^{tg} e^g e^{-e^g} \, dg \\
&= \int_{g=-\infty}^\infty e^{(t+1)g} e^{-e^g} \, dg \\
&= \int_{u=0}^\infty u^{t+1} e^{-u} \cdot \frac{1}{u} \, du \\
&= \Gamma(t+1), \tag{5}
\end{align}$$
where we have employed the substitution $u = e^g$, $g = \log u$, $dg = \frac{1}{u} \, du$, and the definition of the gamma function.  So the MGF of $Y$ is
$$M_Y(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{t(\log \theta + G/\tau)}] = e^{t \log \theta} M_G(t/\tau) = \theta^t \Gamma\left(\frac{t}{\tau} + 1\right). \tag{6}$$
Computing the $m^{\rm th}$ moments from $(6)$ is a bit tedious, since by the generalized product rule
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[Y^m] &= M^{(m)}_Y(0) \\
&= \frac{d^m}{d^m t} \left[ \theta^t \Gamma\left( \frac{t}{\tau} + 1 \right) \right]_{t=0} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k} \frac{d^{m-k}}{d^{m-k} t} [\theta^t]_{t=0} \frac{d^k}{d^k t}\left[\Gamma\left(\frac{t}{\tau} + 1\right)\right]_{t=0} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k} \left[\theta^t \log^{m-k} \theta \right]_{t=0} \frac{\Gamma^{(k)}(1)}{\tau^k} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k} \frac{\log^{m-k} \theta}{\tau^k} (-1)^k B_k(\gamma, 1! \zeta(2), \ldots, (k-1)! \zeta(k)), \tag{7}
\end{align}$$
where $B_k$ is the $k^{\rm th}$ Bell polynomial and we have used the formula shown in the Wikipedia entry for the gamma function.
Further simplification of $(7)$ may or may not be possible, but it does lead to a method of computation for explicit $m$.  A brief table of values is given as follows:
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
m & \operatorname{E}[\log^m X] \\
\hline
1 & -\frac{\gamma}{\tau} + \log \theta \\
2 & \frac{\gamma^2 + \zeta(2)}{\tau^2} - \frac{2\gamma}{\tau} \log \theta + \log^2 \theta \\
3 & -\frac{\gamma^3 + 3 \gamma \zeta(2) + 2 \zeta(3)}{\tau^3} + \frac{3 \gamma^2 + 3\zeta(2)}{\tau^2} \log \theta - \frac{3 \gamma}{\tau} \log^2 \theta + \log^3 \theta
\end{array}$$

@heroup Hey, thank you for helping me ! Let me read through everything step by step & piece by piece first before I asking a question  and thank you very much, I sincerely wish that you receive an abundance of blessings in your life.

Hey @heroup, thanks for your guidance. I am able to follow up from $(1)$ to $(6)$. However, I got a little question on the $(7)$, how can the second line equation transform to the third equation? Based on my understanding, that's due to the Product Rule Applications, so before the third equation in $(7)$, is $\theta^t \frac{d^m}{d^mt} \left[ \Gamma \left( \frac{t}{\tau} + 1 \right)  \right]\bigg|{t=0} + \Gamma \left( \frac{t}{\tau} + 1 \right) \frac{d^m}{d^mt} \left[ \theta^t  \right]\bigg|{t=0}$ , am I on the right track? :)

@Gambit For the product of two differentiable functions $f(x)g(x)$, we have $(fg)' = f'g + g'f$, and $$(fg)'' = f''g + 2f'g' + fg'',$$ and $$(fg)''' = f'''g + 3f''g' + 3f'g'' + fg''',$$ and so on.  The pattern should be clear; the $m^{\rm th}$ derivative would be $$(fg)^{(m)} = \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k} f^{(m-k)} g^{(k)}.$$

@heroup, very appreciate your patience, everything almost crystal clear for me now. I was taking pencil and papers to figure it out, hence the response could be late as I want to make sure I am fully stuck before asking here :)
For $4$ , given Gumbel Distribution , $f = \frac{1}{\beta}e^{\frac{x-\mu}{\beta}} e^{-e^{\frac{x-\mu}{\beta}}}$ , and
saying $\mu=\ln \theta$ and $\beta=\frac{1}{\tau}$, we have $f = -\tau ^2 e^{\tau x}   \left(   e^{{\tau}e^{\tau x}}   \right)$...
How can it related to $Y= \ln \theta + \frac{G}{\tau}$ ?

@Gambit In the same way that if $Z \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1)$, then $X = \mu + \sigma Z \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu, \sigma)$, a location-scale transformation of the "standard" Gumbel distribution $G \sim \operatorname{Gumbel}(0,1)$ of the form $Y = \log \theta + G/\tau$, then $Y \sim \operatorname{Gumbel}(\log \theta, 1/\tau)$.

Thank you @heroup. I understand it now. Wish you have a nice day. Very appreciated! I will go and study the Bell polynomial by my own :) Thank you once again.

If you consider moment generating function of $\ln(X)$, we have
$$
M_{\ln (X)}(t) = E[e^{t\ln(X)}] = \sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{E[(\ln (X))^m]}{m!} t^m
$$
but also
$$
E[e^{t\ln(X)}] = E[X^t] = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{t} f_X(x;\tau, \theta) dx.
$$
If I did computations correctly, the last integral equals to $\theta^{t} \Gamma(t/\tau + 1)$, so we get
$$
E[(\ln(X))^m] = \frac{d^m}{dt^m}\Bigg|_{t=0} \theta^t \Gamma(t/\tau + 1)
$$
which may not have a nicer closed form.

Hi @Seewoo Lee, thanks for the lights... anyway, I wonder is there a book, or website that have the derivation of these thing?
